# Relating exposure time of a camera to number of photoelectrons

Tags: optics, photons, photoelectric-effect, camera

How can we relate the exposure time of a camera to the number of photoelectrons created on the detector? We know the power and the wavelength of light hitting on the camera, quantum efficiency of the camera, and all the other specs such as dynamic range, dark current, temporal dark noise etc.

I saw that the authors of an article preferred to use the number of photoelectrons instead of the exposure time of the camera in their manuscript. That looked much more scientific and I am really curious about the correct way of doing this.

My prediction is: We first need to find the number of photons by dividing the light power by single photon energy. Then, we can multiply the result by quantum efficiency and exposure time to calculate the number of photoelectrons. Is this the correct way or should I include the other factors such as pixel size, noise etc.?

Comment: Photo-generated carriers perhaps? Photoelectrons are something else.

Comment: @Jon Custer yes, probably. I quoted the word directly from the article but they should be the same, you are right.

Comment: @JonCuster Maybe he is right about photoelectrons? Typically in situations where you are detecting XUV radiation you detect photoelectrons...this would actually be the raw data...More context from sahin would need to be had. Setup of this experiment, etc.

Comment: @JoséAndrade I can provide you the link to the article: https://www.osapublishing.org/ao/abstract.cfm?uri=ao-53-3-410
However, the setup is not presented here. They mostly refer to an earlier work: https://www.osapublishing.org/oe/fulltext.cfm?uri=oe-21-5-6584&id=250688
In the latter study, it is clearly expressed that they are using an InGaAs camera: Xenics Xeva 1.7-320.